Beamer: How to define the position of footnotes?
I'm working on a beamer template and I want to move the footnotes to the right side of the slide. Hence, I did this:
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xspace}

\renewcommand\footnoterule{}
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{
    \begin{textblock*}{147mm}(10mm,76mm)
    \hfill
    \insertfootnotemark\xspace \insertfootnotetext
    \end{textblock*}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]
    \frametitle{A DEMO}
    This is a test with two footnotes\footnote{Test1} and anotherone\footnote{More testing}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}

, which worked great for one footnote. Any second and third footnote on the slide is plotted at the exact same position, on top of the other one. Is there any way to define the box of all footnotes and for each individual footnote, such that footnotes appear underneath each other again?
I want the footnotes to be right and bottom aligned, if possible.


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Please also specify how the footnotes should be aligned

Beamer normally uses \raggedright for the footnotes. You could replace it with \raggedleft:
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\title{DEMO}
\author{Max Mustermann}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{xspace}

\renewcommand\footnoterule{}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedleft
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[c]
    \frametitle{A DEMO}
    This is a test with two footnotes\footnote{Test1} and anotherone\footnote{More testing More testing More testing More testing More testing More testing More testing More testing More testing More testing More testing More testing}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}


